# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Content' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in /home/ROOTNAME/public_html/wp-admin/index.php on line 97

Tags: php, wordpress

I cannot access my WP admin anymore after the update of WordPress to v5.5 and the update of several plugins and theme at the same time.
Even if I restore my website to a backup before those updates, I get this error when I try to log in to my WP admin:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Content' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in /home/ROOTNAME/public_html/wp-admin/index.php on line 97

This is the line 97:

```
        'id'      => 'help-co   => __( 'Content' ),
```

And it is part of this code:

```
$screen->add_help_tab(
array(
    'id'      => 'help-co   => __( 'Content' ),
    'content' => $help,
)
```

);

Can someone help me fixing this error?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Count the single quotes in that line. One starts a literal the second stops the literal etc etc

Comment: That leaves the word `Content` just hanging there blowing in the wind, so the compiler is saying, I dont understand